# how to change the authSerivce using map which has to return observable from old version of angular?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-httpclient

I followed the tutorial from https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

you can have a look at it, it is well written but used old version of angular and I am using Angular 8. When I followed the tutorial, I got an error from `auth service` that `map does not exist on type Observable`. SO I tried to put `pipe` but still getting error. What did I do wrong and is the solution here?

**authservice**

```
    login(userName, password) {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.http
          .post(
          this.baseUrl + '/auth/login',
          JSON.stringify({ userName, password }),{ headers }
          ) 
          .map(res => res.json())
          .map(res => {
            localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
            return true;
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }
```

**login OnSubmit**

```
    submit() {
        const controls = this.loginForm.controls;
        /** check form */
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            Object.keys(controls).forEach((controlName) =>
                controls[controlName].markAsTouched()
            );
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;

        const authData = {
            username: controls.username.value,
            password: controls.password.value,
        };

        this.isRequesting = true;
        this.auth
            .login(authData.username, authData.password)
            .finally(() => (this.isRequesting = false))
            .subscribe(
                (result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
                    }
                },
                (error) => (this.errors = error)
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a new version of RxJs than in the example. Need to use *pipe*.
2. Instead of *catch* you need *catchError*

Example:

```
 login(userName, password) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
      this.baseUrl + '/auth/login',
      JSON.stringify({ userName, password }),{ headers }
      )
      .pipe(
          map(res => res.json()),
          map(res => {
              localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
              this.loggedIn = true;
              this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
              return true;
          }),
          catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

I’m not sure that the above code will work for you, since I don’t know what *this.handleError* is.

P.s.If you use angular 8, then change Http to [HttpSlient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)( [Http - deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp))